# How to install libgdiplus on openSUSE?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, opensuse

So, I am a .NET developer and I need to run my project on Linux. I was provided with ssh access to a machine with openSUSE Tumbleweed version 20170403 on it. To run System.Drawing.Common functionality I need a libgdiplus package installed, but if I try to install it via "zypper in libgdiplus" command i get "No provider of 'libgdiplus' found." message. This is like my second time dealing with Linux, so i don't have any clue what the hell i am doing. Thanks for helping me.

So I've tried

```
zypper in libgdiplus
apt-get install libgdiplus
```

they give me the same output:

> 'libgdiplus' not found in package names. Trying capabilities. No provider of 'libgdiplus' found

Comment: Can you show the commands you use to install it? And the output?

Comment: so I've tried 'zypper in libgdiplus' and 'apt-get install libgdiplus', they give me the same output: 'libgdiplus' not found in package names. Trying capabilities. No provider of 'libgdiplus' found

Comment: Have you tried `zypper search libgdiplus`? You might need `zypper install libgdiplus0` instead of just `libgdiplus`.

Comment: adding 0 helped. Thank you! I really exhausted myself with this problem, i've been googling for 4 hours now...you are a life saver!

Comment: Answer added. I wasn't sure as I'm on a different openSUSE version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for a package, use

```
zypper search ...
```

first, in this case

```
zypper search libgdiplus
```

Sometimes, adding `-d` is needed to search for "details", i.e. not only the short package descriptions.

In this case, the package for openSUSE is in fact called `libgdiplus0`, as the search shows. So, to install it, you must specify

```
zypper install libgdiplus0
```